# What creates Cypher/Neo4j "Expected two strings, but got [Ljava.lang.String;@22d9b2a2 and ..." error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've imported a graph looking like this:

```
(x:Person {id:"Pers1"})-[:factoid {name:[" Abt Eberhard "]}]->(u:Source {id:"Source1"})
```

into Neo4j community edition 3.0.7 (installed only today on a Windows 10 machine).

Searching for the whole term in `f.name` works fine:

```
MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source)
WHERE f.name=' Abt Eberhard '
RETURN f.name
```

but using `CONTAINS`, `STARTS WITH`, or regular expressions with `=~`, for example

```
MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source)
WHERE f.name STARTS WITH ' A'
RETURN f.name
```

returns an error similar to

```
Expected two strings, but got [Ljava.lang.String;@38fb2527 and  A
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example data, the `name` property of the `factoid` relationship is a list of strings: `[" Abt Eberhard "]`. Just remove the square brackets and it works with `STARTS WITH` as well:

```
CREATE
     (x:Person {id:"Pers1"})-[:factoid {name:" Abt Eberhard "}]->
     (u:Source {id:"Source1"})

MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source)
WHERE f.name STARTS WITH ' A'
RETURN f.name

╒══════════════╕
│f.name        │
╞══════════════╡
│ Abt Eberhard │
└──────────────┘
```

The equality comparison works, because (presumably) the Cypher engine performs a `toString()`-like operation on the list. But note the difference in the results:

```
CREATE
     (x:Person {id:"Pers1"})-[:factoid {name:" Abt Eberhard "}]->
     (u:Source {id:"Source1"})
CREATE
     (x:Person {id:"Pers1"})-[:factoid {name:[" Abt Eberhard "]}]->
     (u:Source {id:"Source1"})

MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source)
WHERE f.name=' Abt Eberhard '
RETURN f.name

╒════════════════╕
│f.name          │
╞════════════════╡
│ Abt Eberhard   │
├────────────────┤
│[ Abt Eberhard ]│
└────────────────┘
```

Comment: And another clear cut explanation what creates my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. The `name` value is actually a *collection* that contains just one string. Is this intentional?

I am surprised that this query:

```
MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source) WHERE f.name=' Abt Eberhard ' RETURN f.name
```

returns anything, since that query is asking if a collection equals a string, which should either cause an error or at least be `false`.

The "correct" syntax would be something like this:

```
MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source) WHERE f.name[0]=' Abt Eberhard ' RETURN f.name[0]
```

It looks like the other string functions you tried are more picky. For instance, `STARTS WITH` would work with the "correct" syntax:

```
MATCH g=(p:Person)-[f:factoid]-(u:Source) WHERE f.name[0] STARTS WITH =' A' RETURN f.name[0];
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!!